# In ASP.Net MVC controller, how do I get a method to recognize data from JSON and Form-urlEncoded formats?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, post

I'm trying to use ASP.NET code MVC to handle HTTP POST requests as follows:

```
[Route("coreapi/control")]
public class Control : Controller
{
    [HttpPost(userGroups/{groupId}/users/{userId})]
    public int AddRecord(UserRecord record){
        //This even populates the UserId and GroupId fields in record from the route
    }
}
```

The above works for Form-UrlEncoded parameters, but not for JSON.

If I want JSON to work, I need to use the [FromBody] attribute like so:

```
[Route("coreapi/control")]
public class Control : Controller
{
    [HttpPost(userGroups/{groupId}/users/{userId})]
    public int AddRecord([FromBody]UserRecord record, int groupId, int userId){
        //this doesn't look in the route to populate info anymore
        record.GroupId = groupId;
        record.UserId = userId;
    }
}
```

How do i get both to work in a single method?

Comment: I'm curious what happened when `FromBodyAttribute` is missing, is this error you got: `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter`?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I get no errors but all the fields of the UserRecord class are null. when a json string is sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this seems really silly, but from experimentation and reading this [very informative article](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/), it looks like the only way to do this is with two separate methods.

One for form-urlencoded data

```
[Route("coreapi/control")]
public class Control : Controller
{
    [HttpPost(userGroups/{groupId}/users/{userId}/add)]
    public int AddRecord(UserRecord record){
        //This even populates the UserId and GroupId fields in record from     the route
    }
}
```

and one for json:

```
[Route("coreapi/control")]
public class Control : Controller
{
    [HttpPost(userGroups/{groupId}/users/{userId}/addJson)]
    public int AddRecordJson([FromBody]UserRecord record, int groupId, int userId){
        //this doesn't look in the route to populate info anymore
        record.GroupId = groupId;
        record.UserId = userId;
    }
}
```